# Wann benutzt man 'erst' und wann benutzt man 'Zuerst'? Was ist der Unterschied?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, word-choice

Stufe: A1.

Schreiben Sie die Antwort in Englisch bitte.

Beide bedeuten das Gleiche, oder nicht?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The scopes of `erst` and `zuerst` interfere without being synonyms.

In the following cases `erst` can not be replaced by `zuerst`:

> Erst zu Hause erfuhr er, dass seine Oma gestorben war.
>   (Not until beeing at home, he learned, that his grandma has died.)
>
> Ich habe ihn erst gestern noch gesehen.
>   (I have seen him only yesterday.)
>
> Der jüngste Professor der Welt ist erst 19 Jahre alt.
>   (World's youngest professor is only 19 years old.)
>
> Er selbst ist ja schon frech, aber erst sein Bruder!
>   (He is cheeky, but far more his brother!)

In the following cases `zuerst` can not be replaced by `erst`:

> Mal sehen, wer zuerst ankommt, du oder ich!
>   (Let's see, who will arrive first, you or me!)
>
> Reibungselektrizität wurde zuerst an Bernstein beobachtet.
>   (Frictional electricity has been found for the first time ever at amber.)

Answer (score 4):

"Zuerst" always means that something is first. It is typically (sometimes implicitly) followed by "dann" or "danach" (meaning "then" and "afterwards respectively). For example: "Zuerst wasche ich meine Hände, dann fange ich an zu kochen". Or implicit: "Fangen wir an zu kochen?" "Nein, zuerst wasche ich meine Hände. [Dann / Danach können wir anfangen [zu kochen]]".

"Erst" can have the same meaning.
But it can also mean that something is unexpectedly late, for example "Er kam erst um 11:00 Uhr nach Hause" ("He only arrived home at 11:00 o'clock).